# c# ftp write only

Tags: ftpwebrequest, writeonly

The following code will throw an exception when i try to connect to a "write-only" ftp

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp://...);

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

Stream ftpstream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

GetRequestStream() throws a "permission denied" exception since the framework implements the FTP commands as follows:
- open
- user
- pwd

please any help ?

Comment: Can you confirm that the credentials you're using can actually connect and upload to the ftp? Possibly with an FTP client, e.g. [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)

Comment: it's not working with filezilla but only ftp dos.i m sure for the credentials

Comment: with filezila i get : 230 User logged in, proceed
but blocking on get pwd

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/netfxnetcom/thread/44dd4bd4-2404-4dcd-99ad-bcdb013a9d71) thread.

Also, to avoid the PWD behind the scene you could use a .Net FTP client like [edtFtpNet](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/) like this:

```
        var ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.BytesTransferred += new BytesTransferredHandler((o, e) => { Console.WriteLine("Remote Path: " + e.RemotePath + ", Remote File: " + e.RemoteFile + ", Bytes transfered: " + e.ByteCount); });
        ftp.TransferStartedEx += new TransferHandler((o, e) => { Console.WriteLine("FTP Transfer started!"); });
        ftp.TransferCompleteEx += new TransferHandler((o, e) => { Console.WriteLine("FTP Transfer completed!"); });

        try
        {
            ftp.RemoteHost = FTP_HOST;
            ftp.ConnectMode = FTPConnectMode.ACTIVE;
            ftp.Timeout = 120000;
            ftp.Connect();
            ftp.Login(FTP_USER, FTP_PWD);
            ftp.TransferType = FTPTransferType.BINARY;
            ftp.Put(GetBytes("file contents go here!"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:" + e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            ftp.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("FTP Quit!");
        }
```